# Random Contacts saved in my iPhone 6

Tags: iphone

For a while now, I have noticed that my iPhone 6 will randomly delete contacts of the people that I know, and other weird contacts of people that I have never heard of suddenly appear at the same time.

I am fairly sure that it is not due to sync with Facebook or Twitter as I have never heard of these people in my life. It has been rather frustrating and confusing to have to re-save those people's contacts several times.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Check if either

- You're logged in with someone else's icloud or email accounts in settings

or

- Someone you know (kid, spouse, etc.) is using YOUR icloud account on their device.

Easiest way to tell: change your icloud password and see if anyone screams, and if the problem stops.

Another source of them might be if you share a computer and multiple people sync their phones to it, it might be syncing your phone book with the computers'